# JQuery changing th width after multiple plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, tableheader

I am trying to make a table with a scrollable `tbody` within a table using [this plugin](http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/). There are plenty of other questions about jquery or pure-css scrollable tbody elements, but none as involved as mine.

The issue is that I'm also using a jQuery tablefilter plugin which adds an additional header row for filters. When I load the tablescroll plugin, it overrides the table dimensions and my headers no longer match.

The columns are variable width and the tablescroll plugin assumes they are equal length which causes the improper alignment.

I tried resetting them manually using javascript **Here:**

```
var $table = $(".tablescroll"),
$cols = $(".tablescroll tr td").slice(0,5),
$th = $(".fixedHeader tr th");
$table.tableScroll();
$filter = $(".filterRow th");
$.each($th, function(index, value){
      $th[index].style.width = $cols[index]['clientWidth'];
      $filter[index].style.width = $cols[index]['clientWidth'];
});
```

and it adds the correct style attribute to each `th` but the headers keep the same incorrect alignment. This is also the **VERY LAST** javascript loaded on the page.

Here's my **HTML:**

```
<form>
<table class="tablescroll">
          <thead class="fixedHeader">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Site</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>Modified Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
                    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Test Name</td>
                <td>Test Description</td>
                <td>Test Site</td>
                <td>2013-12-18 15:20:05</td>
                <td>2014-01-29 19:36:09</td>
            </tr>
                    </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

I'm curious why my javascript calls add the style but change nothing about the appearance and if I should continue with this plugin or simply work out a pure css solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @jkgm777 said, the plugin removes the headers and creates a new table for them. This threw off all the css and js that was referencing the header class in the specific table which caused the behavior.

My solution will require a pure-css version due to sorting and filtering functionality that will not work across tables.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the inline style for the table instead of using Javascript?

```
<table style="width:##px;">
```

or for the header column directly

```
<tr><th style="width:##px;"></th></tr>
```

Comment: That's what the js accomplishes if you view page source. However, abstracting it through js allows me to use it in multiple places like I want.

Comment: Your headers change depending on the data? What about min-width and max-width to have a range? Your table header's width will be re-sized depending on the content of the row, if you put a max-width and the content of a cell is too long, it will wrap your text in more than 1 row.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your response. The columns each have a defined width, it's just not the same from column to column. I edited my comment to reflect why I used js.

Comment: I see. Do you have a footer (not the table footer, but a footer you load on every page dynamically) that might be loading other scripts?

Comment: Yes but the page was formatted correctly until I added the tablescroll plugin. I know that is causing the problem so I'm trying to run a fix after it is initialized.

Comment: The plugin you're using creates another table just for the headers. Why don't you try to do what that plugin does manually? I mean, create a table at the top for your headers containing only the thead attribute, and add another table below with only the tbody attribute. Put the 2nd table inside a div and add the css 'overflow:auto' to that div. This will work if you're doing it only to a few tables, otherwise, it will be a nightmare.